# Test behavior differs between Node.js & browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, jestjs

The `URL` object in the browser (in this case Chrome) compared to Node.js do not behave the same.  As a result, I'm getting tests that pass when run in Node, but the behavior doesn't match in the browser.

To demonstrate, here's a simple `parseURL` function that tries to parse a URL from a string.  If it can't parse it properly, then it instead returns a URL that equates to a Google search using the string provided.

```
function parseURL(query) {
  const formattedQuery = query.includes('://') ? query : `http://${query}`;

  try {
    return new URL(formattedQuery);
  } catch (err) {
    return new URL(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`);
  }
}
```

And a simple Jest test to demonstrate how this function is expected to work:

```
describe('parseURL', () => {
  it('accepts valid URL string', () => {
    expect(parseURL('https://example.com')).toEqual(
      new URL('https://example.com')
    );
  });

  it('prepends protocol when missing', () => {
    expect(parseURL('example.com')).toEqual(
      new URL('http://example.com')
    );
  });

  it('converts search queries', () => {
    expect(parseURL('example.com lol jk')).toEqual(
      new URL('https://www.google.com/search?q=example.com+lol+jk')
    );
  });
});
```

The first two tests have matching behavior for both Node.js and the browser.  Great!

The third test, however, passes in Node.js even though the behavior doesn't match inside the browser.  Specifically, when calling `new URL('http://example.com lol jk')` in Node.js, an error is raised.  In the browser though, no error is raised, and instead a URL object is returned:

```
{
  href: "http://example.com%20lol%20jk/",
  origin: "http://example.com%20lol%20jk",
  protocol: "http:",
  username: "",
  password: "",
  hash: "",
  host: "example.com%20lol%20jk",
  hostname: "example.com%20lol%20jk",
  href: "http://example.com%20lol%20jk/",
  origin: "http://example.com%20lol%20jk",
  password: "",
  pathname: "/",
  port: "",
  protocol: "http:",
  search: "",
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  username: ""
}
```

How can I be confident that my tests reflect what is actually happening in the browser when using objects like this?

Comment: browser norm is to encodeURI() which changes spaces to `%20`. Might need to a little bit of string normalizing yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `URL` is inconsistent between implementations.

It is expected behaviour that

```
new URL('http://example.com lol jk')
```

throws an error, it's not a valid URL. It's correctly implemented in Node.js and Firefox but not in Chrome (which is supposedly referred as 'the browser' here).

It's safe to rely on Node.js implementation in Jest. In case the consistency is required in production, `URL` needs to be replaced with spec-compliant implementation, `whatwg-url`.

Comment: You're correct that I'm using Chrome.  I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: Does `whatwg-url` altogether replace the browser implementation, or just polyfill if it's not already defined?

Comment: I updated the answer to mention it is an implementation, not a polyfill. It can be used as a polyfill by assigning it to `window.URL`. But it's better to import it and use instead of `URL` global. If you're able to not modify globals to suit your needs, that's always preferable.